# Does eating bananas help digestion?

Tags: food, digestion

I don't know what I am asking is silly or not, but I have always heard that eating a banana after a meal helps in digestion.

Some people says before food while others say after.

Is it a fact or some silly myth?

Comment: I just ate bananas on their own by a 300km bicycle tour, and they did not help by the digestion...

Comment: This question is on-topic I think but it would also be a very good fit on [skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) if you can prove it is a notable claim.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to Skeptics.SE

Comment: I have heard same for Papita.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bananas seem to contain lots of dietary fiber that help move consumed food through the intestines ([popular article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/429663-do-bananas-help-digestion/)) thereby promoting digestion. Whether one should eat bananas before or after dinner is probably a debatable subject ([Yahoo forum](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080513031420AA6QbDc)).